# How to fix the songs order in folders in Odyssey?

Tags: honda, audio, odyssey

I noticed that in my Honda Odyssey 2012, when I arrange MP3 songs by folders on a USB flash drive, the car's audio (factory built/stock head unit, not 3rd party or aftermarket) does not acknowledge the folders and play all tracks in a different order. This order is not by file name, song name, artist name or the sorting order in MP3 file meta data. The shuffle option is disabled too.

Also, each time I turn on the audio, the order of songs is changed.

On Civic 2012, I don't see this problem at all.

Comment: Is this a stock head unit or aftermarket? If aftermarket, what brand/model is it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

That head unit is rather primative.  It will "sort"  (actually NO sort) and play the songs in FAT (File Allocation Table) order.

Which is pretty much the sequence they were loaded onto the USB.

Which I'm very sure *sucks* for your purposes.

If you are IT inclined, there are utilities out there that allow you to sort files by certain vectors (artist, name, creation, size, etc.) and re-write the FAT table in an order you find more useful.

Otherwise, I'm sorry to say (I actually *hate* to say)  "It is what it is..."

**On Edit:**

The downvote probably came from the perception that this is not a pure "automotive" question, and maybe better suited to a car stereo forum.  However, I done been learned long ago and according to our charter, your question is valid, reasonable, and belongs.  I hope I gave a reasonable answer, albiet it's not great news.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What tools/utilities you are referring to?

Comment: It's a bit out of my wheelhouse (but I'm so old I actually know and understand what the old *File Allocation Table* really means).  If you google "fat sorter" you will get enough results to keep you busy for days.  (And probably some unexpected "adult" links as well.)  [sigh]

Answer (score 0):

Download Rename Master.  Open your mp3 folder which is in your ideal play order.  Add numbers from 1000 to 3000 to the beginning of the file name. and save.

Download MP3TAG program. Select first song and use "file name to title" option. Now title is exactly same as file name,   1000xyz. Select all and you are done.

Honda player will sort the files using title which is your ideal order.

Comment: While this would work, you now can't find a specific track unless you can remember the codename that you renamed it to.